# Empty form submissions

Tags: solspace-freeform, forms, snaptcha

I launched a site last week with two forms that are getting lots of spam. The strange thing is that they're not getting the usual viagra message but instead they're totally blank.

I've set the forms up in the same way as lots of other client's websites and don't have problems with any others.

I can't work out how these are getting through as I have jQuery validation on the form that doesn't let a user submit an empty field. I also have Snaptcha installed and set to medium to try to stop this, but still they're getting through.

The other strange thing is that I added some IP addresses to the EE blacklist module yesterday and still they come through.

The IP's I added were:

- 31.28.170.*
- 62.149.10.*
- 62.149.15.*

But have since received blank messages from IP's including:

- 62.149.10.11
- 62.149.15.142

Here's a link to one of the forms: https://workshoprecruitment.co.uk/jobs/resources

Any ideas how these blank submissions are getting through or suggestions on stopping it?

Any ideas welcome,

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: I don't see a form on the page you have linked to.

Comment: There's an email capture form for each of the downloads. If you check the source code or click one of the titles you'll see the form